# Visual studio not respecting "When build or deployment errors occur, do not launch" when running unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio Professional 2019, version 16.5.1. I have it set so that if a build fails, it is not supposed to run tests.

[image: VS ignoring this setting]

But if I have build errors in my project, it runs the tests anyway. This is true regardless of whether I run the tests with control-R control-T, or by right clicking in the test explorer.

How can I get it to respect my setting?

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? It has its own test runner.

Comment: not using ReSharper